# Delete all target json fields with a single command

Tags: json

I wonder if it is possible to remove all JSON fields that match a given criteria with a one-liner command (e.g. using sed). If it is not possible with a one-liner, I would like the most simple/smallest approach.

Example: I decided that I don't longer need the "id" field.

Input JSON file:

```
{ 
   "games": [
      {"id": "1","name": "Mario", "game": "nintendo"},
      {"id": "2","name": "Luigi", "game": "nintendo"},
      {"id": "3","name": "Sonic", "game": "sega"}
    ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{ 
    "games": [
       {"name": "Mario", "game": "nintendo"},
       {"name": "Luigi", "game": "nintendo"},
       {"name": "Sonic", "game": "sega"}
     ]
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: should it be an array `[ {...}, {...}, {...}]` ?

Comment: @diginoise I edited it

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and you have plenty options e.g:

- **Whitelisting** the properties you want:

  ```
  cat games.json | jq '[.games[] | {name, game}]'
  ```

  see this in action on [jq>play](https://jqplay.org/s/9LL4debrRD).
- **Blacklisting** the properties you don't want:

  ```
  cat games.json | jq '[.games[] | del(.id)]'
  ```

  see this in action on [jq>play](https://jqplay.org/s/qdo5gD7_hU).
- **Traversing the whole tree** to remove matching properties:

  ```
  cat games.json | jq 'del(..|.id?)'
  ```

  see this in action on [jq>play](https://jqplay.org/s/mQViqkV_-2).

Comment: what if the input file structure is not as simple as the one in the example? Is it required to put the entire json structure within quotes?

Comment: @JoãoMatos  not sure how much more complex is your json, but if you only want to remove named properties, see the blacklisting scenario above (after edit)

Comment: It didn't work with a more complex json file. If 'id' is a field within an object which is inside of an array of another object which in turn is inside of an array of another object.. and so on, those commands are not successful (don't know why)

Comment: @JoãoMatos you would need to use more elaborate jq expression and I would discourage using regex to process any structured data format, the same way one should not do regex + xml. String(regex) based tools will be faster, but it could be a risky strategy as it's more error prone. Post the actual structure and I am sure there is an expression for your need.

Answer (score 0):

Use the foreach approach and delete inside the loop:

```
let obj = JSON.parse ( yourJson );

Object.keys(obj).forEach( (key) => { 

    delete obj[key]; 

});

yourJson = JSON.stringify( obj );
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to do this with sed. The following command works for the above example:

```
sed 's/\("id":\).*\("name\)/\2/' games.json
```

How does this work:

```
sed 's/\(FROM\).*\(UNTIL\)/FROM_INCLUSIVE UNTIL_INCLUSIVE/' input_file
```

This command substitutes everything that sits between the string in **FROM** and the string in **UNTIL** with an empty string. Then we can specify whether those strings should be kept or not: \1 will keep the string in **FROM** and \2 will keep **UNTIL**, omitting means exclusion. In the example above we are saying that we want to remove everything that exists between  **"id":**  and  **"name** while excluding the former (there is no \1) and including the latter (there is a \2).